# Set of sequences -roots of unity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, magma

Consider $G_n$ as the multiplicative cyclic group given by the $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

$$G_n = \left\{ e^{ 2ik\pi/n} \mid 1\leq k \leq n \right\}$$

Now construct a sequence from each $G_n$ by $(e^{2i1\pi/n}, e^{2i2\pi/n},\dots, e^{2ik\pi/n},\dots,e^{2in\pi/n}, 0, 0, 0,\dots$).

Now consider the set S of all such sequences, 
$$S=\left\{(e^{2i1\pi/n}, e^{2i2\pi/n},\dots, e^{2ik\pi/n},\dots,e^{2in\pi/n}, 0, 0, 0,\dots)   :  1\leq n \lt \infty\right\}$$
Will I be right in concluding that no matter what operation I impose on $S$, the structure of $S$ will never be a semi-group/vector space/normed vector space?

I wondered about the practical utility of creating $S$. Any help?

An observation is that $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is the only limit (obtained by pointwise convergence of first sequence) contained by $S$ (when $S$ is viewed as a subset of $C^n$.
 It contains no other elements that are obtained by pointwise convergence of each sequence. The pointwise limit of each sequence is of the form $(1,1,....,\underbrace{1}_{n^\text{th}\text{ place}},0,0,\dots)$.

Comment: I am just bothered by the fact that no matter what I do I can not see $S$ as more than just a set!

Comment: I mean, some things are just sets. It's not really a tragedy, it's just a fact of life. You can cheat a TON and force a group structure, but basically that amounts to putting $S$ in bijection with $\Bbb Z$ and using its natural group structure, which is almost surely totally against what you're looking for.

Comment: @AdamHughes : What is a TON ?

Comment: @AdamHughes : How can it be shown that S can not have any other structure apart from being just a set?

Comment: It means *any* countably infinite set is in bijection with $\Bbb Z$ so can always be given a group structure just by using the bijection. But such a map is just a map of *sets* so you're not getting any information about the underlying set other than its cardinality. There's nothing of the original set's personality left with such a construction.

Comment: It cannot be shown, because technically there are many group structures on it, even ring structures, or algebras, or fields, from assorted set bijections, it just doesn't have any obvious *natural* ones which depend anything on the actual elements as sequences of complex numbers.

Comment: @AdamHughes : Okay, I know it by other names - equipollence, equivalence, etc. Yeah, I do not need any information about its cardinality. I know that $Card(S) = Card(Z)$.

Comment: @AdamHughes : Technically,  the structure constructed from elements of $Z_2$ and given by $S$ = {$ (0,0,0,...),(0,1,0,0,...),(1,0,0,0,...),(1,1,0,0,....)$} also has other structures but it is not only a set but a group under addition as well! Why should it hold in this case and fail in the above?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different set with no connection to yours. I could easily say "technically the structure constructed from elements of $\Bbb Z$ and given by $S=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\ldots \}$ also has other structures--namely anything you can do to $\Bbb Z$", since it literally **is** $\Bbb Z$. You're asking about a *specific* set. For **that particular set** there is no natural thing. Pick a different set, different rules might apply.

Comment: @AdamHughes : You have spoken intuitively. It seemed that way to me too! But now, how do you say that with certainity? Or rather why should I take what you say for  granted? How can it be established that for that particular set, it is ONLY A SET?

Comment: Again, you're being too inexact. If you mean it is only a set under componentwise multiplication/addition/et cetera then you just check those operations by-hand and verify that it's not closed under the operation, and you're done. You don't **really** mean it's only a set period, since we've already discussed you could give it a strange structure based on bijections with other sets.

Comment: @AdamHughes : That is not what I want to know. I want to see if a certain binary operation(s) can be imposed on S. IF you say you can not impose such an operation, then I seek its justification. (Here, one always seeks the validity of statements that can be justified). I had my own intuition to begin with and I would not have posted it here to have the intuitive feel echoed back.

Comment: By the way, I disagree that $(1,0,0,\dots)$ or $(1,\dots,1,0,\dots)$ are limit points of $S$. The elements of $S$ converge (pointwise at least) to $(1,1,\dots)$.

Comment: Also how can $S$ be viewed as a subset of $R^n$?

Comment: @GregMartin :Sorry, it is $C^n$. Yes, you are right!

Comment: @GregMartin : Each element of S converges pointwise to (1,1,...1(n-th place),0,0,....) and not (1,1,....).

Comment: There seems to be some confusion as to whether the elements in $S$ are sequences or $n$-tuples, i.e., whether they are elements of $\Bbb C^\infty$ or $\Bbb C^n$ for some $n$. The pointwise limit depends on what you mean there.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Sorry again... oh, I really cant keep myself from making the silliest possible mistakes! The elements of S are in $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

> Will I be right in concluding that no matter what operation I impose on $S$, the structure of $S$ will never be a semi-group/vector space/normed vector space?

Adam Hughes has essentially answered the question in the comments. I am simply going to pile (a lot) more detail onto his explanations. In my opinion, the most honest answer to this question is:

> Technically no, but **yes**.

To expand on this briefly before getting heavy: If someone were to come up and ask me this question, I would simply say, "yes, that is correct". This is (formally) a complete lie, and if I was asked to explain logically why that was correct, I would be completely unable to, because it's not true. This is a reasonable follow-up question, and I am much more likely to be caught in this lie than in saying some other blatantly false thing like "$.999...\neq 1$", so you might wonder what would drive me to this kind of behavior. That is what I will try to get at with the rest of this answer.

---

Since I will spend a lot of time discussing technicalities and intuitions, here are a few that I just want to smooth over right away:

- $S$ is not a subset of $\Bbb C^n$ for any $n$; in fact, no element of $S$ is an element of $\Bbb C^n$ for any $n$.
- Elements of $S$ are probably not usefully thought of as sequences, although they are technically sequences.
- Instead, we start with a set called $\Bbb C^\Bbb N$ which you can think of as containing complex vectors with (countably) infinitely many elements.
- It is easy to check that $\Bbb C^\Bbb N$ is a vector space.
- But notice that $$\{(1,0,0,\dots); (0,1,0,\dots); (0,0,1,\dots), \cdots\}$$ is not a basis of $\Bbb C^\Bbb N$. The span of this set is called $\Bbb C^\infty$, and it is easy to check that $S\subset\Bbb C^\infty$.

---

To explain why the statement is not true, a counterexample will suffice: I will prove that $S$ is a field; in fact, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. Fortunately, the counterexample will also elucidate why my answer is "yes".

We begin by noting that $S$ is countable, and therefore there exists a bijection $S\to\mathbb Z^+$. We can do better than that, we can write one down explicitly. Define the *support* of a vector in $\Bbb C^\infty$ to be the number of nonzero entries: this number is finite, non-negative, and zero only for the zero vector, so the support $\sigma$ is a well-defined function from $\Bbb C^\infty\smallsetminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb Z^+$. It follows from the definition on $S$ that the restriction of $\sigma$ to $S$ is a bijection.

Let $\phi$ be your favorite bijection $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Q$. Remember that all bijections have inverse functions. Then define $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ as functions $S\times S\to S$ such that

$$s\oplus t = \sigma^{-1}\Big(\phi^{-1}\Big( \phi(\sigma(s))+\phi(\sigma(t)) \Big)\Big)$$
$$s\otimes t = \sigma^{-1}\Big(\phi^{-1}\Big( \phi(\sigma(s))\cdot\phi(\sigma(t)) \Big)\Big)$$

The inner addition and multiplication are the ordinary operations on $\mathbb Q$. These functions are well-defined, and the field axioms follow by the injectivity of $\sigma^{-1}$ and $\phi^{-1}$. For the incredulous, the associativity of multiplication is proved below; others are similar.

$$s\otimes (t\otimes u) = \sigma^{-1}\Bigg(\phi^{-1}\Bigg( \phi(\sigma(s))\cdot\phi\Big(\sigma\Big( \sigma^{-1}\big(\phi^{-1}\big( \phi(\sigma(t))\cdot\phi(\sigma(u)) \big)\big)\Big)\Big) \Bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$= \sigma^{-1}\Bigg(\phi^{-1}\Bigg( \phi(\sigma(s))\cdot\Big( \phi(\sigma(t))\cdot\phi(\sigma(u)) \Big) \Bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$= \sigma^{-1}\Bigg(\phi^{-1}\Bigg( \Big(\phi(\sigma(s))\cdot \phi(\sigma(t))\Big)\cdot\phi(\sigma(u)) \Bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$= \sigma^{-1}\Bigg(\phi^{-1}\Bigg( \phi\Big(\sigma\Big( \sigma^{-1}\big(\phi^{-1}\big( \phi(\sigma(s))\cdot\phi(\sigma(t)) \big)\big)\Big)\Big) \cdot \phi(\sigma(u)) \Bigg)\Bigg) = (s\otimes t)\otimes u$$

[It's the sort of proof that only an algebraist could ever love.]

Once we are convinced that $S$ is a field under these two operations, it is easily determined that $\phi\circ\sigma$ is a homomorphism $S\to\Bbb Q$; since it is bijective, we have that $S\cong \Bbb Q$.

---

My hope is that, after seeing this construction, you automatically understand why my answer is "yes". If this is true, you can skip this section.

Else, let us consider this famous quote of Halmos (emphasis mine):

> Don't just read it; fight it! Ask your own questions, look for your own examples, discover your own proofs. **Is the hypothesis necessary**? Is the converse true? What happens in the classical special case? What about the degenerate cases? **Where does the proof use the hypothesis**?

If the theorem is "$(S,\oplus, \otimes) \cong (\Bbb Q,+,\cdot)$ as fields", and the proof is as above, one might wonder about these two instructions. What is the hypothesis? I posit that the hypothesis is many-layered: in order of depth, first it is the construction of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, then the construction of $S$, and then the construction of $(\Bbb Q, +, \cdot)$.

The construction of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ is clearly of critical importance, and the proof uses them many, many times to prove the field axioms and then the isomorphism.

But what about the construction of $S$? Go look at it. I'll wait.

Did you see it?

The proof *never* uses the construction of $S$. It says it does, but if you read carefully, you see that the only fact that it uses about $S$ is that $\sigma$ is a bijection $S\to\Bbb Z^+$; that is, that $S$ is countable.

We are then *forced* to conclude the following theorem, because the proof is identical:

> For a suitable construction of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, any countable set $A$ has $(A,\oplus, \otimes) \cong (\Bbb Q,+,\cdot)$ as fields.

Well, that was unexpected.

How about the construction of $\Bbb Q$? Go back and look again.

Really, do it.

Your eyes are not deceiving you. The construction of $\mathbb Q$ is *never* used. Again, it says it is, but the only facts that we are using about $\mathbb Q$ is that it is countable (for the existence of $\phi$) and that it is a field (for the well-definition of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$).

That means we are forced to conclude this still more general theorem:

> For any countable field $F$ and a suitable construction of $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, any countable set $A$ has $(A,\oplus, \otimes) \cong F$ as fields.

But wait, it gets better.

The only reason countable shows up is because of the intermediate $\mathbb Z^+$. If we had a single bijection $A\to F$, it could play the role of $\phi\circ\sigma$, and the proof goes through. Therefore, we can strike *countable* from the theorem above, replacing with the additional hypothesis that $|F|=|A|$.

And now the *coup de grâce*: where do we use the fact that $F$ is a field? The answer is, to prove the field axioms for $A$. But the technique used to prove them can be used to do this for any algebraic structure. If $F$ is a ring, then $A$ is a ring. If $F$ is a quasigroup, then $A$ is a quasigroup. And so on. Now we have a family of nearly-identical theorems about arbitrary sets being algebraic structures.

But for this generality, we pay a very, very high price. As Adam so eloquently put it (emphasis mine):

> There's nothing of the original set's *personality* left with [this] construction.

---

Okay, so… what, exactly? These are pathological examples, clearly. We just have to exclude them, and then we can focus on the real ones.

Except it's not that easy. The problem is, *every* isomorphism between two algebraic structures is by definition a bijection, and is therefore a candidate for $\phi\circ\sigma$. Therefore, if we exclude fields made by this construction, we exclude every field. Even good, wholesome fields like $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z_{81}$.

This is a sad state of affairs. What are we to do?

The unfortunate answer is that we cannot do anything. All sets are all fields (modulo cardinality concerns), all groups are rings, all monoids are $\Bbb C$-algebras; we must accept it. The only thing to do is admit that most fields are !@#%^&!@ and try to focus on the ones that aren't.

---

So let us interpret your question with this in mind. Is there an algebraic structure on $S$ that isn't !@#%^&!@ ? The important thing to remember is that !@#%^&!@ is not formally defined, so the answer to this question is inherently subjective. Moreover, a negative answer is almost never possible. There may be a theorem that strongly suggests the answer is no, but you cannot actually be certain that one of the pairs of operations skirts around the hypotheses of that theorem and yet is less !@#%^&!@ than you would have guessed.

However, there is one way that we can safely say that a group is not !@#%^&!@ with very little controversy. There is some group that is not !@#%^&!@, for example $\Bbb C$. If we can represent $S$ as a *subgroup* (or at least isomorphic to a subgroup) of this group, then it is also not !@#%^&!@. In other words, not-!@#%^&!@-ness is a hereditary property.

Along these lines, here is some evidence that $S$ does not have this property:

- $S$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb C^\infty$.
- Every element of $S$ lies in the infinite direct product of unit circles union the origin. But $S$ is not a submonoid of this monoid.
- $S$ is not a submagma of any countable product of finite magmas, despite being defined by countably many finite magmas (indeed, groups).

Comment: I am about 99.999% sure this construction also works with topologies and the widgets that make topologies, but I'm too tired to write out the details. There may be some category-theoretic explanation of which properties play nice with this construction, but I don't actually know any category theory.

Comment: Elements of S are in $C^\infty$. Its something I know but I dont know why I got it wrong... thanks!

Comment: Eric: Thank You very much for the detailed explanation. However, I am not convinced about the additive and multiplicative inverses to make S a field, given my definition of S.

Comment: But wait... suppose you come up with a suitable explanation to my comment above, there is something in the next part that I do not follow. What was that thing about homomorphism/isomorphism? Does not isomorphism preserve the structure imposed on the set and bring about the same effect on both the sets? What do you mean by your statement regarding $\phi o \sigma$ ?

Comment: @Manasi: Existence of inverses is straightforward. The inverse of $s$ is $\sigma^{-1}\big(\phi^{-1}\big(\phi(\sigma(s))^{-1}\big)\big)$, or replace $s^{-1}$ with $-s$ for additive; the inverse is well defined because $\phi(\sigma(s))$ is a rational number. This construction also allows for all three generalizations. // Yes, $S$ as I have constructed it is *isomorphic* to the rational numbers. It has the same structure of addition and multiplication.  $\phi\circ\sigma$ is simply the bijection which exhibits the desired isomorphism; it is worthwhile to check that it is indeed a homomorphism

Comment: This does not make sense. Say $\sigma(s)= 5$, say. Let $\phi(5) = k$, say where k is some rational number. Now since $k\neq 0$ , you have $\frac{1}{k}$ is again a rational number which may not be a positive integer and then one is in trouble since $\sigma^{-1}(\frac{1}{k})$ would not exist!

Comment: @Manasi: I think you saw an older version of the comment; it now correctly says $\sigma^{-1}\phi^{-1}$ instead of $\phi^{-1}\sigma^{-1}$. Now the concern is removed because $\phi^{-1}(1/k)\in\Bbb Z^+$ and so you can take $\sigma^{-1}$ of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16257/discussion-between-eric-stucky-and-manasi).

Comment: Eric:  From our definition of $S$, we have that $\sigma(t) \neq 0$, so $\phi(\sigma(t))\neq 0$. This means that additive identity does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote by $s_n$ the sequence constructed from $G_n$. Let us define $$s_m*s_n=s_d{\rm\ where\ }d={\rm lcm}(m,n)$$ Voila! $S$ is now a semi-group!

Comment: It is also a monoid.