# Why multiplication should be a secondary binary operation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Isn't every multiplication resumed in a simpler summing operation? For instance: $5 \times 2 = 5 + 5$; or $5 \times 1/2 = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2$; or $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1 \times 1/4 = 1/4$. Why does a ring structure have to consider multiplication? Multiplication is a special case of summation... such as incountable other imaginable operations based on summation.

Why not have ! (a unary operation) for a secondary operation? $4! = 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 4 \times (3 + 3) = (3 + 3) + (3 + 3) + (3 + 3) + (3 + 3)$. Or division such as $5/2$ equals $2.5$ an operation?

I'm only asking because it seems unnecessary (to me) to consider multiplication as a ring axiom, as multiplication is a special case on summation.

Comment: try $\pi*\pi$ in real numbers

Comment: Please use mathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Multiplication of matrices is not repeated addition. There are more rings between heaven and earth than are dreamt of in your suggestion

Comment: A search on this site for "[multiplication repeated addition"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiplication+repeated+addition)" produces many relevant items.

Comment: Since you brought up rings, let us consider a typical ring,  the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients. Please explain how you plan to multiply the polynomial $x$ by the polynomial $x$ using repeated addition.

Comment: I'm not stating anything! I'm just asking you to prove me that multiplication is (or is not) dependent on summation. I'm trying to get a grasp on number theory, and I need this before I continue.

Comment: MJD, thank you for the link. Should I know there was already a debate on this problem I probably would not have asked this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is satisfactory (drawing from MJD's comment):

Consider the ring of polynomials $\Bbb Z[x]$ under the usual operations. We claim that for any $r\in\Bbb Z[x]$, there is an $p\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and unit $u\in\Bbb Z$ the following non-equality holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n r \neq urp$$

Note this is false in the integers, in particular if we set $r=1$ (we need $u$ to avoid a technical issue; you can't get to negative numbers by only adding $1$). We might say that this is the property of being ''built'' from repeated addition.

However, for any $r$ let $p=x$. Observe that $\sum r=nr$, and recall that $\Bbb Z[x]$ is an integral domain with units $\pm 1$. Thus, if $nr=urx$ then $\pm n=x$, but this is absurd because $x\notin\Bbb Z$.

Perhaps you would like to skirt this theorem by making the obvious objection that the sum is only over natural numbers. This is true, but the sum is only dependent on the number of summands; the summands does not depend on $n$ at all. It's certainly plausible that we could define an special addition indexed by ring elements, but I'm not sure in what sense you could still call that "repeated addition".

This is a hint that addition does not suffice to define multiplication. A complete proof is unlikely because the statement is not particularly well-defined: it is true that there are abelian subgroups of rings which do not inherit the product structure, but it is also true that every abelian group admits *some* product structure. However, these are typically very uninteresting; I go into more detail in my [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888581/set-of-sequences-roots-of-unity/888834#888834).

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe I'm missing the point, at all... And, since I'm new here, relearning basic mathematics, I'm hopping you'll forgive me... I'll make the assumption that, maybe, the base proposition for this question, for multiplication to have any meaning beyond added summation, is that:

There exists n, m, x, y (in whatever set you want to prove it) such that the following non-equality holds:

[image]

And, if I'm seeing it correctly, I just need an example where this is true. An example of this non-equality in a certain set of numbers (any or all) such that, for those sets, the added summation does not hold.

Comment: Pure *existence* these objects is trivial: go into the integers and use $(n,m,x,y)=(2,3,1,4)$ to get $1+1\neq 4\cdot 4\cdot 4$.